# php appending/writing to a file

Tags: php, append, fwrite

I am using the following script to write in a file include.php
this script searches for files in files and images folder and writes in include.php
files directory contains the files

```
*sintel_trailer1.mp4
*sintel_trailer2.mp4
```

images dir contains the following files

```
*sintel_trailer1.jpg
*sintel_trailer2.jpg
```

php code

```
$path = array("./files/","./images/");
$path2=      array("http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."/files/","http://".$_SERVER['S ERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."/images/");
$start="";
$Fnm = "./include.php";
$inF = fopen($Fnm,"w");
fwrite($inF,$start."\n");

$folder = opendir($path[0]);
while( $file = readdir($folder) ) {
       if (($file != '.')&&($file != '..')&&($file != 'index.htm')) {
            $folder2 = opendir($path[1]);
            $imagename ='';
            while( $file2 = readdir($folder2) ) {
                if (strstr($file2, '.', true) == strstr($file, '.', true)){
                    $imagename = $file2;
                }
            }
            closedir($folder2);
        $result="{\nlevels: [\n{ file: \"$path2[$key]$file\" }\n],\nimage: \"$imagename\"\ntitle: \"$file\"\n},\n";
        fwrite($inF,$result);
       }
}
fwrite($inF,"");
closedir($folder);

fclose($inF);
```

I am getting the following result

```
{
levels: [
{ file: "sintel_trailer1.mp4" }
],
image: "sintel_trailer2.jpg"
title: "sintel_trailer1.mp4"
},
{
levels: [
{ file: "sintel_trailer2.mp4" }
],
image: "sintel_trailer2.jpg"
title: "sintel_trailer2.mp4"
},
```

But I need this result

```
{
levels: [
{ file: "sintel_trailer1.mp4" }
],
image: "sintel_trailer1.jpg"
title: "sintel_trailer1.mp4"
},
{
levels: [
{ file: "sintel_trailer2.mp4" }
],
image: "sintel_trailer2.jpg"
title: "sintel_trailer2.mp4"
},
```

**Update**

error log shows
Warning: Wrong parameter count for strstr() in index.php on line 15

**Line 15**
if (strstr($file2, '.', true) == strstr($file, '.', true)){

Comment: don't use strstr() for pulling apart filenames. what if you had `Ep1.of.3.mp4`?  There's `basename()` and related functions for a reason.

Comment: @Marc so what do you suggest ?

Comment: I have updated the post for error log
kindly suggest

Comment: You need PHP 5.3 at least for the `true` parameter in strstr: http://php.net/strstr

Comment: @Marc so is there any alternative for older php version ?
MY php version is 5.2.17

Comment: revamp to use basename(), or upgrade to a 'modern' php. 5.2's fairly old, especially now that 5.4 is available.